# How to transmit binary data over CIP using AT commands?

Tags: gsm

I'm trying to transmit binary data using Ai-Thinker A6 GPRS module.The problem is that it does not support the AT+CIPSEND=[length] command (looks like a firmware bug). If you use a simple AT+CIPSEND command without length, CTRL-Z (also as a zero byte) is interpreted as input completion, which means that, for example, not all numbers can be passed as data.
I did not find any information about escaping in these commands. 
What can I do with this?

Last datasheet: [link](http://wiki.ai-thinker.com/_media/gprs/docs/aithinker_a6_a7_a6c_a20_at_command_v1.03.pdf) 
Summary Ai-Thinker GPRS page: [link](http://wiki.ai-thinker.com/gprs)

Comment: Check the frimware revision of your device and then check what does that revision support.

Comment: Yes, the FW of my modules is outdated. I can't reflash it, official Download Utility bricks modules. Tested with Windows 10, 8, 7, XP, and Linux (wine); also tried 3 different USB-UART chips (including FT232).
Another reason is that the batch of devices has already been manufactured, and I don't want to solder the wires to every A6 and update the firmware.

Comment: Ok, I found how to reflash an A6 module. Download tool works correctly only on Windows XP, only with FT232X USB-UART only with old official driver (2012), only if UART wires (including ground) no longet then 5 cm (baudrate is ~1M). Any deviation leads to the impossibility of starting the module.

Answer (score 4):

AT command set for GPRS network is standardized so you can search for help 
on other pages like this [[link1]](https://vsblogs.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/tcp-connection-over-gprs-using-sim900-and-at-commands/)
and this [[link2]](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/data-call-at-commands-to-set-up-gprsedgeumtslte-data-call/)

In addition to that, be advised to check examples from this link too [[link3]](http://www.hwkitchen.com/news/at-command-tester-tutorial-for-gsm-gps-playground/).

Example bellow is just a fragment copied/edited from [this page](https://www.slideshare.net/DevrhoidDavis1/at-command-set-for-sending-data-via-tcp-using-sim900), so I believe that can be good starting point.
Be advised not to use specific commands related to the manufacturer in order to keep yours code reusable.

GPRS users can activate or deactivate a socket.
Then user can establish a TCP or UDP connection to a remote server 
using the AT command tester.

Once a TCP or UDP connection is established through a socket, users 
can use other application services such as HTTP, FTP, SMTP etc.

For example:

```
Command: AT+CREG? 
Success Result: +CREG=1,1 OK 
Note: This means the SIM is ready and has connected to the network. 

Command: AT+CGATT? 
Response: +CGATT: 1 
Note: Check if the SIM has Internet access. 

Command: AT+CIPSTATUS 
Response : OK 
Note: Query the IP settings. 

Command: AT+CIPMUX=0
Response: OK 
Note: Configure modem to make a single port open for connections. 

Command: AT+CSTT="www.server.com","","" 
Response: OK 
Note: Connect to Internet (Parameters are as follows; 
"APN","USERNAME","PASSWORD", 
have in mind that both the Username and Password are blank in the above instance. 

Command: AT+CIICR 
Response: OK 
Note: Bring up wireless network. 
Ensure that the modem has a SIM with credit and/or has a data plan is activated. 

Command: AT+CIPSTART="TCP","584.287.743.894","80" 
Response: OK CONNECT OK 
Note: Make a TCP Connection to the server at 584.287.743.894 on Port 80, the Default TCP and HTTP port. 

Command: AT+CIPSEND 
Response: > 
Note: This command allows you to make request of the server. You enter 
your request after the prompt (>). 

Commands may either be GET, PUT or POST. 
Each command has a specific manner in which the command is to be 
written. 
GET request to the server example is below. 
--------
GET /my_page.html HTTP/1.1 
Host: 124.456.798:80 Connection: keep-alive .... Connection 
Successful!

Command: AT+CIPCLOSE
--------
```